# Dojo AMD module changes reference of "this"

Tags: dojo, amd

I'm really confused as to some behavior I'm seeing in trying to learn the AMD style of Dojo.  When I instantiate my module/object, "this" refers to the object in my constructor.  I make a call to an internal function, and "this" inside that internal function refers to the Window object.  So when I get to this.attachMapEventHandlers I get a "Object [object global] has no method 'attachMapEventHandlers'" error.  What am I doing wrong?  UPDATE: I found lang.hitch, which seems to indicate that the async nature is what's tripping me up, but I'm confused on how to implement a solution.

my script inside index.html:

```
require(["javascript/layout", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", 
        "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-attr", "dijit/Toolbar", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/Dialog","dijit/ProgressBar", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function (layout, dom, domAttr) {
            mapControl = new layout();
```

layout.js:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {
return declare(null, {
    action:"pan",
    activeMeasureTool:"",
    aerialLayer:"",
    legendLayers:"",
    loadedServices:"",
    popup:"",
    resizeId:0,
    constructor: function() {
        this.init();
    },
    init: function() {
        require(["esri/map", "esri/config", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/geometry/Extent"], 
            function(Map, config, SpatialReference, Extent) {
            //custom map requires a proxy to function properly.
            esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "../sdc_devdata/proxy.php";

            var spatRef = new SpatialReference(2276);

            var startExtent = new Extent(2481416.32087491, 6963246.42495962, 2501196.36936991, 6980267.92469462, spatRef);
            var appFullExtent = new Extent(2396699.46935379, 6872369.60195443, 2607745.94404633, 7107335.22319087, spatRef);

            map = new Map("map", {extent: startExtent, isZoomSlider:true, logo:false, sliderStyle:"large"});
            this.attachMapEventHandlers();
            this.createLayers();
            this.handleLayerVisibilityChange();
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put 'this' in another variable, like _this, and use _this in your internal function,like

```
init: function() {
         var _this= this;
        require(["esri/map", "esri/config", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/geometry/Extent"], 
            function(Map, config, SpatialReference, Extent) {
            ...
            _this.attachMapEventHandlers();
            _this.createLayers();
            _this.handleLayerVisibilityChange();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that you could do to resolve this.

Firstly, you could add your required dependency to the `define` array so you don't need to do an asynchronous require within the constructor of the class.

That would look like:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "esri/map", "esri/config", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/geometry/Extent"], function (declare, Map, config, SpatialReference, Extent) {
  return declare(null, {
    action: "pan",
    activeMeasureTool: "",
    aerialLayer: "",
    legendLayers: "",
    loadedServices: "",
    popup: "",
    resizeId: 0,
    constructor: function () {
      this.init();
    },
    init: function () {
      //custom map requires a proxy to function properly.
      esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "../sdc_devdata/proxy.php";

      var spatRef = new SpatialReference(2276);

      var startExtent = new Extent(2481416.32087491, 6963246.42495962, 2501196.36936991, 6980267.92469462, spatRef);
      var appFullExtent = new Extent(2396699.46935379, 6872369.60195443, 2607745.94404633, 7107335.22319087, spatRef);

      map = new Map("map", {
        extent: startExtent,
        isZoomSlider: true,
        logo: false,
        sliderStyle: "large"
      });
      this.attachMapEventHandlers();
      this.createLayers();
      this.handleLayerVisibilityChange();
    }
  });
});
```

OR you could save the current scope of `this` to something in the closure when doing the require

```
init: function () {
  var that = this;
  require(["esri/map", "esri/config", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/geometry/Extent"],
    function (Map, config, SpatialReference, Extent) {
      //custom map requires a proxy to function properly.
      esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "../sdc_devdata/proxy.php";

      var spatRef = new SpatialReference(2276);

      var startExtent = new Extent(2481416.32087491, 6963246.42495962, 2501196.36936991, 6980267.92469462, spatRef);
      var appFullExtent = new Extent(2396699.46935379, 6872369.60195443, 2607745.94404633, 7107335.22319087, spatRef);

      map = new Map("map", {
        extent: startExtent,
        isZoomSlider: true,
        logo: false,
        sliderStyle: "large"
      });
      that.attachMapEventHandlers();
      that.createLayers();
      that.handleLayerVisibilityChange();
    });
},
```

EDIT: your third option would be using lang.hitch, which lets you specify the scope of `this` in the the callback function.  To use it, you would add `dojo/_base/lang` to you define() dependency list, and wrap the require  callback in `lang.hitch(this, function(){});`

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang"], function (declare, lang) {
  return declare(null, {
    //...
    init: function () {
      require(["esri/map", "esri/config", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/geometry/Extent"],
        lang.hitch(this, function (Map, config, SpatialReference, Extent) {
          //this now refers to the instance of the class
        }));
    }

  });
});
```

I would strongly suggest going with the first option, since it is consistent with the entire use of AMD (declaring what dependencies a module needs before it executes, rather than loading it on the fly).

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  Accepted the first one